# Retrieve session data Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I'm working on a messaging system and want the user's userid to be posted to the database along with the message. Right now, the message is posting to the database, but with a user ID of 0.

How can I get the user ID from the session data to post to the database along with the message? Sidenote: I'm using Tank Auth for authentication. (From the mysql side, user_id in the message table is a foreign key referencing id in the users table).

**Controller**

```
function index() {

    if ($this->input->post('submit')) {
            $id = $this->input->post('user_id');
            $message = $this->input->post('message');

            $this->load->model('message_model');
            $this->message_model->addPost($id, $message);
        }
    }
```

**Model**

```
function addMessage($id, $message) {
        $data = array(
            'user_id' => $id,
            'message' => $message
        );

        $this->db->insert('message', $data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken directly from [CI's documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html):

> **Retrieving Session Data**
>
> Any piece of information from the session array is available using the
>   following function:
>
> ```
> $this->session->userdata('item');
> ```
>
> Where item is the array index
>   corresponding to the item you wish to fetch. For example, to fetch the
>   session ID you will do this:
>
> ```
> $session_id = $this->session->userdata('session_id');
> ```
>
> Note: The
>   function returns FALSE (boolean) if the item you are trying to access
>   does not exist.

So, if you have a piece of session data named `user_id`, you would access it like this:

```
$user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I saw that in the user guide, but thought that because I'm using Tank Auth that the session syntax would somehow be different. I tried about 10 different times to come up with something that would work--didn't realize the syntax would be the same.

Answer (score 1):

For tank_auth, get the user_id using the following, and then assign that to your sessions

```
$user_id    = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();
```